# Defining preprocessor macro to line of macro definition

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Let's say I have the following macro definitions (line numbers included):

```
41 #define MACRO1 
.
.
52 #define MACRO2
```

How do I define MACRO1 so that, at compile-time, it resolves into a number that corresponds to the line number MACRO1 is defined on? (in this case 41)

How do I define MACRO2 so that, at compile-time, it resolves into a concatenation of a predefined string (for example foo) and a number X where X is equal to the difference between the line number of MACRO2 (52) and the line number of MACRO1 (41)?

Given the above, MACRO2 would resolve to foo11 since it is a concatenation between the predefined string 'foo' and the difference between the 2 lines numbers 52 and 41.

Is this possible?

Comment: Seconding Basile: you can't do that. But maybe we can still help with the problem you were trying to solve with that if you tell us about it :)

Comment: I want to take a bunch of C/C++ files and change all meaningful names and variables into something that makes no sense...For example: int CountDown becomes int HJhHh38hgrh

Comment: This is called [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)). It might not work as well as you dream of it.

Comment: Why not? If all function names and variables are changed into gibberish at compile time it'll make it at least somewhat more difficult to make sense of.

Comment: Read more about [decompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) and define exactly what do you want to protect. In some cases a legal protection is enough. A good example is the [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) free software license.

Comment: People who wanna reverse engineer code don't care about licenses

Comment: A C++ *obfuscator*, then. Did you try existing ones, and why didn't they fit? If you want to make yours, I'd expect the easiest route to be a compiler plug-in, not manual macro fiddling. Also, if you want to hide your source code, distributing a compiled, optimized binary with no symbols is easier and more robust.

Comment: People who want to reverse engineer don't care about obfuscated C++ code. They study the binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you want with the usual [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Read [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

However, remember that C (or C++, etc...) files could be generated (by some program or script). You could use some *other* preprocessor for that generation (e.g. [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), or your own script or program).

Then, you simply need to configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) for that purpose. If you use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), edit your `Makefile`; if you use [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), edit your `build.ninja` file, etc....

Such basic [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques are quite common in practice; in many large programs, some of the C or C++ code is generated. Some generators (e.g. [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) or [rpcgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN)) are quite common, and appeared in the previous century.

As an example, the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (mostly coded in C++) has about a dozen of C++ code generators.

Notice that modern [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) enable [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) and their [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading); so in some cases it even is worthwhile to generate some C or C++ code at runtime, compile it as a plugin, and load it (e.g. using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) on Linux) to use it. Then beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Consider also using some [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) etc....

BTW, recent C++ compilers can be extended with plugins (e.g. [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)) or used as a library (e.g. [libclang](https://clang.llvm.org/)). Many (academic, or domain specific) languages are [compiled to C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), and some are compiled to C++ (e.g. [felix](http://felix-lang.org/)).

Comment: Do you know any free tools (preferably command line for Windows) that'll batch process a group of C/C++ files and provide a list of all functions and variables ?

Comment: That is a different question. You might consider coding your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) or using [libclang](https://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: No, it's part of the scope of this task. To auto-list all function names and variables and then - intelligently - change the names into gibberish at compile-time (or before compilation). I'm starting to think that it'll be easier just to produce the header file before compilation.

Comment: Whoever is assigning to you such a task is incredibly naive. As long as he is paying you for that, you are free to lose your time.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: No, don't have time. I gave references. Also, I don't think that your source code is worth to be protected such a way (a powerful entity could still reverse-engineer, and most entities don't care).